# HttpListener problems: Each HTTP request results in two contexts returned by HttpListener

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, httplistener

I have been putting together a little embedded HTTP server in a windows service app that listens for updates coming from other devices on the network that speak HTTP.

**For each HTTP request, the code that processes the request/response is executed twice, I expect it to run only once.**  I tried the code using the AsyncGetContext method and using the synchronous version GetContext - the end result is the same.

**Code**

```
public void RunService()
{
    var prefix = "http://*:4333/";
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
    try
    {
        listener.Start();
        _logger.Debug(String.Format("Listening on http.sys prefix: {0}", prefix));
    }
    catch (HttpListenerException hlex)
    {
        _logger.Error(String.Format("HttpListener failed to start listening. Error Code: {0}", hlex.ErrorCode));
        return;
    }
    while (listener.IsListening)
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext(); // This line returns a second time through the while loop for each request
        ProcessRequest(context);
    }
    listener.Close();
}

private void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context) 
{
    // Get the data from the HTTP stream
    var body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    _logger.Debug(body);

    byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OK");
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
    context.Response.ContentLength64 = b.Length;

    var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    output.Close();
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing, I have run out of ideas to track down the issue.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* certain there is only one request?  Make doubly sure by watching Wireshark while running your test.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at OpenRasta, which does all this for you ;-) - we've successfully used it to embed an HTTP listener in various applications both as the core of an application and as a bolt on for monitoring, etc. - https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki

Comment: @Inuyasha, that was the problem, the web browser also sends a request for favicon.ico.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, the issue was I was using a web browser to test the HTTP connection and by default a web browser also sends a request for favicon.ico.  So two requests were actually coming across.  Thank you to @Inuyasha for suggesting I check things out with Wireshark.

Comment: Holy crap, that was bothering me.

Comment: How did you end up handling this? That is, is there a way to respond only once for a single web page request from the user (even though technically 2 requests are made)?

Comment: @danns87, you do have to process both requests -- just detect anything that you don't care to handle (such as the favicon) and return a 404 error.  Or actually return a favicon.